# Javascript + Convert "<b>" to actual bold font

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am using the [jTwitter plugin](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/11/jquery-twitter-plugin-update-jtwitter.html) to get Twitter feeds. I am using it combined with a function that makes the links in the returned text click-able.

That function looks like this:

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>"); 
}
```

Everything works fine, except that the person who is sending the tweets is always trying to make parts of it in bold. And it looks like this `<b>Bla</b>`. It looks like this on his twitter site and also on my page.

I dont know what he does wrong and I dont care, I am just wondering if I could transform those in actual bold at my site by adding another few lines to the function above?

Comment: What do you mean by 'actual bold'? `<b>` and `<strong>` tags *are* HTML's default methods for marking up bold content (the first is to simply make text bold, the second to imply that a semantic weight should be given to the text within)

Comment: The above code has nothing to do with it.

Comment: B stands for bold font : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font_style.asp Are you sure that your problem lies there?

Comment: I probably wasnt able to express what I really wanted to say. Of course I know what <b> and <strong> is. However, in his twitter feeds and therefor in my site there is written "<b>Bla</b>" instead of **Bla**. But look at gion_13´s answer. He understood what I meant and it works now :) Thanks for the help everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note the 'g' flag that tells the replacement to apply to all of the matches.

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text
       .replace(exp,"<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>")
       .replace(new RegExp('&lt;b&gt;','g'),'<b>')
       .replace(new RegExp('&lt;/b&gt;','g'),'</b>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the source, there's a good chance that it i actually `&lt` and `&gt` instead of `<` and `>`.  so do a regex that looks for `&lt;b&gt;`

Comment: You were right! Thanks a lot! However I am gonna mark gion_13´s answer since I just had to copy and paste his modification, where he added the regex to look for "&lt;b&gt;". I hope thats fine with you :)

Comment: @Andrej You could +1 DGM's answer.

Comment: several people answered at once... ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but is the Twitter plug-in returning the HTML escaped -

```
&lt;b&gt;
```

if it is you could replace the escaped content -

```
replace(new RegExp('&lt;b&gt;','g'),'<b>').replace(RegExp('&lt;/b&gt;','g'),'</b>')
```

Answer (score 0):

the html characters have been encoded

try this

http://www.prodevtips.com/2008/10/21/jquery-plugin-html-decode-and-encode/